# using GNU Parallel for pagination

Tags: api, rest, unix, quickblox, gnu-parallel

I like GNU Parallel and have tried to use it for pagination but need help to get it working successfully. Basically, I am following the use cases on the Quickblox API guide to get data:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Get_related_records

The maximum number of records one can retrieve is 100 per page, and one can only retrieve a page at a time. These are specified via the -d parameter. I want to use GNU Parallel to obtain pages 1..79.

I found a thread that explains how to use GNU Parallel when you have parameters that take on many different values but haven't been able to successfully adapt it to my case.

[GNU Parallel - parallelize serial command line programs without changing them](http://www.biostars.org/p/63816/)

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

```
curl -X GET -H "QB-Token: 7de49c25f44e557aeed1b635" -d "page=3" -d "per_page=100" https://api.quickblox.com/users.xml > qblox_users_page3_100perpage
```

Comment: Did you walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks! Will go through this tutorial again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want output in different files:

```
parallel 'curl -X GET -H "QB-Token: 7de49c25f44e557aeed1b635" -d "page={}" -d "per_page=100" https://api.quickblox.com/users.xml > qblox_users_page{}_100perpage' ::: {1..79}
```

If you want it in a single big file:

```
parallel -k 'curl -X GET -H "QB-Token: 7de49c25f44e557aeed1b635" -d "page={}" -d "per_page=100" https://api.quickblox.com/users.xml' ::: {1..79} > qblox_users
```